# SQL Server: filtering data with multiple criteria within criterias

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am using SQL Server 2017 and trying to clean up my data set using "AND/OR" in a where statement

This is what I have so far, but it is not working.

```
WHERE 
    ([Campaign] NOT LIKE '%Search%') 
    AND (([Campaign] = '2018 BRAND' 
          AND [Tactic] <> 'Display' 
          AND [Date] NOT BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-27')
         OR 
         ([Campaign] = '2017 BRAND' 
          AND [Date] NOT BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-07'))
```

Output:

```
Row   Channel     Campaign        Tactic     Date        Visits
----------------------------------------------------------------
1     Digital     2017 Brand      Display    1/1/2017     43
2     Search      2018 Search     Search     2/3/2018     50
3     Digital     2018 Brand      Video      4/10/2018   102
4     Digital     2018 Local      Display    4/9/2018     82
5     Digital     2018 eLocal     Video      3/28/2018    79
6     Search      2018 Search     Search     4/5/2018     30
7     Digital     2017 Local      Display    1/4/2017     22
8     Search      2017 Search     Search     4/5/2017     21
9     Digital     2018 Brand      Display    2/2/2018     43
10    Digital     2018 Brand      Display    2/24/2018    71
```

The 3 things I am trying to remove are:

1. All Search Campaigns (Row 2, 6, 8)
2. All data between 1/1/2017 through 1/7/2017 for the '2017 Brand' campaign (row 1)
3. All data between 1/1/2018 through 4/29/2018 for the '2018 Brand' campaign and is a 'Display' Tactic (rows 9 and 10)

Comment: Why not split your delete query up into manageable chunks instead of trying to do it all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the rows, then I think `or` is more appropriate:

```
WHERE ([Campaign] NOT LIKE '%Search%') OR
      NOT ([Campaign] = '2018 BRAND' AND Tactic = 'Display' AND [Date] BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-27') OR
      NOT ([Campaign] = '2017 BRAND' AND [Date] BEWEEN '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-07')
```

Logic as you have is a little tricky.  My approach is to use `NOT` so you can see each condition and simply keep everything that doesn't match.